# Does Linux immediately allocate memory for process after mmap()?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

I am reading the source code of `mmap()`, and I found the Linux kernel will make the files map into the `vma` struct. `vma` only represents memory areas. So, will the OS immediately allocate physical memory for the process after `mmap()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Linux **may defer** allocation of the physical memory, requested by `mmap`, until that memory will be accessed.

When application accesses an unmapped memory, *page fault* exception is triggered; when handle this exception, Linux may map that accessed memory, allowing the application to continue.

Comment: the “unmapped memory” mentioned above should be area allocated in vma but not mapped in page table. :-)

Comment: Yes, being listed in `vma` gives a chance for unmapped memory to be mapped on page fault. But that page fault is caused by access to **any unmapped memory**, being it in `vma` or not. This is what my post talsk about.